# Star plugins for Symfony

Tags: php, plugins, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I use Symfony **1.4.12** .
If i install http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfWidgetFormJqueryRatingPlugin or http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/mpStarRatingPlugin

i have error:

```
  You try to install a symfony 1.0 plugin.                                                                       
  Please read the help message of this task to know how to install a plugin for the current version of symfony.
```

previously without a problem i installed sfGuardDoctrinePlugin. How can i fix it?

Comment: what does the help message says?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the package was not updated. Did you tried to use the svn trunk version?